# CSV to JSON from a CSV string

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I want to use [CSVtoJSON](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) to process a CSV to an JSON object. But I do have a CSV string and not a file as described in the docs as `csvFilePath`.

```
const csv=require('csvtojson')

csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath) <-- tried CSV string here
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
})
```

but it failed. Any way to use a CSV string here but not an actual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you wish to load the CSV for CSVtoJSON from a string and not a file?

A quick visit to the [documentation](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#from-csv-string-to-csv-row) shows the following solution:

```
csv()
  .fromString(csvString)
  ...
})
```

Comment: Reading helps! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this library:

```
// convert csv into Json
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;

var converter = new Converter({});
converter.fromFile(yourcsvfilepath, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```